# Does any event fire when returning with Safari v. 12(+) back button?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mobile-safari

I'm trying to find some handle to detect that a page is shown after a back button in Safari. I have gone through numerous suggestions in and outside StackOverflow, but most of them are several years old and none of them seem to work on Safari 12.0 anymore.

I have tried especially `onpageshow`:

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
  console.log("Onpageshow fired, event.persisted: ", event.persisted);
}
```

...and `onreadystatechange`:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  console.log("Onreadystratechange fired, readyState: ", document.readyState);
}
```

Both fire during initial page load as expected, but neither one fires after a back button. Naturally neither `DOMContentLoaded` nor `load` fire, either.

My problem is an input text field, which has a custom autocomplete implementation. I have to turn autocomplete `off` for that field, because otherwise the browser autocomplete will display over the custom suggestions. (`Autocomplete=off` and `https` have both been stated elsewhere as reasons, why a text field on a form gets cleared during forward/back.) I'm solving this by storing the value in another (not displayed) input field, and restoring the visible field from there using javascript. Works like a charm using `DOMContentLoaded` in Chrome, but I cannot find any event which would trigger in the latest (also mobile) Safari and let me run the replacement.

Otherwise the backward-forward-cache in Safari works great and runs very quickly, so I wouldn't like to disable it either.

EDIT: Still cannot answer my question, but figured out a workaround to my problem. In case someone lands here with the same issue: Persistence of the text input values over forward/back really seems dependent on the `autocomplete` setting. Therefore, if instead of a static setting I set `autocomplete=off` for the form when the input gets focus:

```
myInput.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  document.getElementById('my-form').autocomplete="off";
});
```

...and back on, when the input loses focus:

```
myInput.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  document.getElementById('my-form').autocomplete="on";
});
```

...the text field content persists accessing another link and returning with a back button in both Chrome and Safari (as of Nov 2018 versions on a Mac).

I would still be happy to find an answer to the original question.